# What should I use dictionary or list in my case?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a text file which stores the image path and its label path such as

```
/JPEGImages/1.jpg /Class/1_label.png
/JPEGImages/2.jpg /Class/2_label.png
/JPEGImages/3.jpg /Class/3_label.png
/JPEGImages/4.jpg /Class/4_label.png
...
/JPEGImages/10000.jpg /Class/10000_label.png
```

In my task, I will read the text file and store in a dictionary/list/array such that easily to access in a single loop as

```
for i in range 10001
   print ('image path', ...[i])
   print ('label path', ...[i])
```

What should type of data should I use? This is my current code but it only save the last path

```
with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        img, gt = line.split()
        img_path = data_dir + img
        gt_path =  data_dir + gt
        img_gt_path_dict["img_path"]=img_path
        img_gt_path_dict["gt_path"] = gt_path
for i in range (10001):
  print (img_gt_path_dict["img_path"][i])
  print (img_gt_path_dict["gt_path"][i])
```

Comment: instead of dict list is possible ? Actually your problem with dict elements. You can only store one value with one key. So try list or change the key as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of tuple to store your data.

**Ex:**

```
res = []
with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        img, gt = line.split()
        img_path = data_dir + img
        gt_path =  data_dir + gt
        res.append((img_path, gt_path))

for i,v in res:
  print("Image Path {0}".format(i))
  print("label  Path {0}".format(v))
```

**Using a Dictionary**(*as requested in comments*)

```
res = {}
c = 0
with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        img, gt = line.split()
        img_path = data_dir + img
        gt_path =  data_dir + gt
        res[c] = {"img_path": img_path, "gt_path": gt_path}
        c += 1

print res
```

Comment: You are use the for `i,v`, but I just want to `for i`. Any better way?

Comment: if you use just 'for i' then you will get a tuple of both values(image & lable).

Comment: How about use dictionary? Because the `i` value is determined by other condition. For example, we just `for i in range (start_index, end_index)`

Comment: If you can use numbers as key then you can use a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, could you update your answer use dictionary or list such that I can use loop as `for i in range (start_index, end_index)`

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I understood my expected.

Comment: Instead of manually keeping the index c, you can use `enumerate`

Comment: @Moberg: You are right. I just made a sample code snipped to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
img_gt_path_dict["img_path"]=img_path
img_gt_path_dict["gt_path"] = gt_path
```

use like this :

```
img_gt_path_dict[img_path]=img_path
img_gt_path_dict[gt_path] = gt_path
```

Because in dict you cannot duplicate key.Thats why it only stores last value.
 So you can use list instead of dict or the complete image_path and gt_path store in a list and give in dict .
    or
like this

```
img_path_list = []
gt_path_list = []
with open('files.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    img, gt = line.split()
    img_path = data_dir + img
    gt_path =  data_dir + gt
    img_path_list.append(img_path)
    gt_path_list.append(gt_path)
img_gt_path_dict["img_path"]=img_path_list
img_gt_path_dict["gt_path"] = gt_path_list
print (img_gt_path_dict["img_path"])
print (img_gt_path_dict["gt_path"])
```

Comment: You are use two lists. My expected is one list because I have to shuffle the list. If I use two lists as your solution, then I shuffle one list, the other list will not shuffle as same index

Comment: then there is another solution is that first one I mentioned,  key also you have to give the same img_path or key you can use as numbers in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to create a dictionary of list that is:

```
paths = {}
paths['img_path'] = []
paths['gt_path'] = []
```

now modify your code as follows

```
paths = {}
paths['img_path'] = []
paths['gt_path'] = []
with open('file', 'r') as f:        
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        img, gt = line.split()
        paths['img_path'].append(img)
        paths['gt_path'].append(gt)
    l=len(paths['gt_path']) #length of the list
    for i in range(l):
        print "img_path: "+paths['img_path'][i]
        print "gt_path: "+paths['gt_path'][i]
```